# Get IP address from hostname in LAN

Tags: c#, windows-7, network-programming

I found many samples on how to get a hostname by an IP address, how can I get the IP address of a host in the LAN?

Comment: What did you try? Ive seen many examples of this.

Comment: I think the same has been answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271724/get-all-ip-addresses-on-machine), does that help you? (includes sample code)

Comment: hi..yes...i found the answer..it is helpful..thanks all!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
public static void DoGetHostAddresses(string hostname)
{

   IPAddress[] ips;

    ips = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostname);

    Console.WriteLine("GetHostAddresses({0}) returns:", hostname);

    foreach (IPAddress ip in ips)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("    {0}", ip);
    }
}
```

i got this from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx

Comment: And here is the original of above (if deeper dig is wanted); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Here is simple code if you want to get the IP Address(V4) from your pc.

Import this library into your class

```
using System.Net;
```

Initialize and declare these variables into your codes. They contain hostname, ipaddress and an array of Host Addresses:

```
string HostName = Dns.GetHostName().ToString();

IPAddress[] IpInHostAddress = Dns.GetHostAddresses(HostName);

string IPV4Address = IpInHostAddress[1].ToString(); //Default IPV4Address. This might be the ip address you need to retrieve

string IPV6Address = IpInHostAddress[0].ToString(); //Default Link local IPv6 Address
```

Open your command prompt, just type "ipconfig" and press enter.Once you are done, you could check if the string IPV4Address matches to IPv4Address in our pc.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you know the name of a machine, you can use [`Dns.GetHostAddresses`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx). Your network DNS should recognize it as LAN computer and return proper IP.

Answer (score 1):

Use Dns.GetHostEntry(hostname) instead of obsolete Dns.GetHostAddresses.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an excellent example of how it is doing: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/854/How-To-Get-IP-Address-Of-A-Machine

Answer (score 0):

you could use the windows management classes to do this, it also works for remote machines that are in the same domain (but I don't know if they need to enable or disable any security or policy settings for this to work). for example:

```
public List<NetworkAdapter> GetAdapterList()
{
    ManagementClass mgmt = new ManagementClass("Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration ");
    ManagementObjectCollection moc = mgmt.GetInstances();
    List<NetworkAdapter> adapters = new List<NetworkAdapter>();

    // Search for adapters with IP addresses
    foreach(ManagementObject mob in moc)
    {
        string[] addresses = (string[])mob.Properties["IPAddress"].Value;
        if (null == addresses)
        {
            continue;
        }

        NetworkAdapter na = new NetworkAdapter();
        na.Description = (string) mob.Properties["Description"].Value;
        na.MacAddress = (string) mob.Properties["MACAddress"].Value;
        na.IPAddresses = addresses;
        adapters.Add(na);
    }
    return adapters;
}
```

and to access a remote machine create the management class like this instead:

```
ManagementClass mgmt = new ManagementClass
    (\\\\servername\\root\\cimv2:Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration);
```

this approach may get you more IPs than just the ones that have been registered in the DNS.