# How to get IP of computer on lan if you have the computers name, using c#

Tags: c#, ip, lan

I'm currently writing a C# program to connect one computer to another on lan.
I have the computer name of the receiving computer but the ip is dynamic so it will change from time to time.

How would I get the lan IP adress of the receiving computer? (the one that goes like 192.168.1.# )

Comment: duplicate.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11931582/get-ip-address-from-hostname-in-lan

Comment: I apologize, I tried searching but didn't know it was called hostname

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming based on your assumption you are looking for the first IPv4 ip address you can use the following:

```
String name = "Name";
IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(name);            
// OR you can get the name of the current computer using 
// IPHostEntry ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());                

// Get the first IPv4 address
IPAddress ip = ipHostInfo.AddressList.Where(n => n.AddressFamily == AddressFamily.InterNetwork).First();
```

Comment: I can't seem to get the ".Where" part working it isn't recognized.

Comment: 4.5  is it part of as specific namespace?

Comment: This was 4.0 but should work in 3.5 as well.  The Where is linq so you need a reference to using System.Linq;

Answer (score 1):

> [Dns.GetHostAddresses Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.dns.gethostaddresses.aspx)

you can resolve Host name to IP as follows

```
string hostName = "www.Google.com";
IPAddress[] addresslist = Dns.GetHostAddresses(hostName);

foreach (IPAddress address in addresslist)
{
   string ip = address.ToString();
}
```