# Display IP Addresses in a Rich text box

Tags: c#, ip

I have a problem with a C# Application I am making. I am trying to get all IPs to display in a textbox within a windows form by simply clicking a button. I currently have a base to work with:

```
    private void btnIP_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         NetworkInterface[] ipadapters = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces();
        string iptemplate = @"
        Network adapter: {0}
        IP:              {1}";

        string IPText = "";

        foreach (NetworkInterface AdapterIP in ipadapters)
        {

            IPText = IPText + String.Format(iptemplate,
            AdapterIP.Name,
            AdapterIP = ipadd());

        }
            txtOutput.Text = IPText;
        }
```

However, I am just not understanding whether I can do this using the

`using System.Net.NetworkInformation;`

If someone can just explain to me how I can take IPs from there and display it, it would help a lot. I have seen people query DNS to retrieve a hostname etc, but I just want to show all IPv4 and IPv6 addresses for all adapters.

I am just not understanding it. I know that I need to keep the foreach() method but not sure how to build out this code to make it work. Note: I have it working for a descriptions and everything for all adapters but I've created a separate button solely dedicated to IPs.

Comment: What bit don't you understand? This SO question goes into some detail: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c ...until you explain exactly what you don't understand.

Comment: I have done this before, but I did it for a CompactFramework application and used a lot of P/Invokes, I'm not sure if there exists a more managed way to do this. But, you are correct that you should **not** have to query DNS !!

Comment: Seems duplicate question  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271724/get-all-ip-addresses-on-machine?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

```
var ipEntry = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (var ip in ipEntry.AddressList)
{
   if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetworkV6)
   {
    //IPv6
   }
   else if (ip.AddressFamily == System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
   {
    //IPv4
   }
}
```

Comment: This way it would only display 1 adapter (random). I want to build the whole adapter list and then display only the IP address including the name of the adapter and at the top hostname of the computer.

Comment: @Maddox Are you using WPF or Winforms? And to confirm, you're looking to only display the local IP address/adapter name of the computer?

Comment: WinForms and I'm trying to list all the adapters on the local machine. Including: Name, Description and IP Address (v4, v6) of those adapters.

Answer (score 1):

```
string hostName = Dns.GetHostName();

string myIP = Dns.GetHostByName(hostName).AddressList[0].ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is a great post about how to do this.  It provides all the info you should need.

[How to get the IP address of the server on which my C# application is running on?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1069103/how-to-get-my-own-ip-address-in-c)

Basically it's this:

```
var host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
foreach (IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
{
    var localIP = ip.ToString();
    //do more here...
}
```