# How can I get a list of available ip addresses on IIS server?

Tags: c#, iis

When using IIS 7 Manager to create a web site, you can set the new site's ip address by selecting from a drop-down list. Is there a way to programmatically obtain this list?

I do not see it in `applicationHost.config`, so I'm not sure where to look.

Thanks.

Comment: Check out this answer, quite relevant : 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271724/get-all-ip-addresses-on-machine

Answer (score 0):

Based on the link provided by Kzest, it looks like there are two ways of accomplishing this. In the examples below, I am screening on AddressFamily to only show items that look like 'xxx.yyy.zz.q'.

Also, the second method also returns the 127.0.0.1 address, which, for my purposes makes it less useful.

```
private void showIpAddresses()
{
  //using System.Net
  IPHostEntry hostEntry=Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
  foreach(IPAddress ipAddress in hostEntry.AddressList)
    if(ipAddress.AddressFamily.Equals(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
      Console.WriteLine(ipAddress.ToString());
}

private void showIpAddresses2()
{
  //using System.Net.NetworkInformation
  foreach(NetworkInterface nwi in NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces())
  {
    IPInterfaceProperties ipProperties=nwi.GetIPProperties();
    foreach(UnicastIPAddressInformation ipAddress in ipProperties.UnicastAddresses)
      if(ipAddress.Address.AddressFamily.Equals(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork))
        Console.WriteLine(ipAddress.Address.ToString());
  }
}
```

Either of these meets my needs and answers the question. Thanks to Kzest for pointing me in the right direction.