# How to get all local IP addresses?

Tags: c#

i want retrieve all local ip addresses which is connected to network...

I am doing this by following code

```
private string GetLocalIP()
{
        IPHostEntry host;
        string localip = "?";
        host = Dns.GetHostEntry(Dns.GetHostName());
        foreach( IPAddress ip in host.AddressList)
        {
        if(ip.AddressFamily== AddressFamily.InterNetwork)
        {
            localip = ip.ToString();
            listBoxIPS.Items.Add(localip);
            return ip.ToString();                
        }
        } return "127.0.0.1";
}
```

but it retrieves only my local ip address not others please help me how to get other local ip addresses thank you..

Comment: You can look into this topic for an answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5271724/get-all-ip-addresses-on-machine

Comment: Define all ip addresses. YOu mean all on your machine? All somewhere magically on the same building?

Comment: i mean to say we have four computers in home. Here i am getting only my IP address not other 3 machines through my code which is above mentioned.

Comment: and this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4042789/how-to-get-ip-all-hosts-in-lan

Comment: Alright let me see thanks

Comment: No Carsten Konig its not up to my requirement

Answer (score 0):

Try to use .NET classes Dns and IPAddress to convert Hostname into IP Address in C#.

For detail check this -

http://www.morgantechspace.com/2014/04/Get-List-of-Network-Computer-Names-in-C-Sharp.html